# How do I export functions from profile.d scripts for use in interactive shells?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, profile

I have some scripts that I install in */etc/profile.d* which define functions that should be exported and made available on the command line. Example script looks like:

```
# This function should be available as a command.
function gcd () {
}

# Bash completions for gcd
_gcd_completions () {
}

complete -F _gcd_completions gcd
```

That should make a command called `gcd` available in terminals.

It works fine in login shells, but it doesn't work (i.e. "command 'gcd' not found") in interactive shells, like if I log into X11 then start a console from there.

I found a conversation [here](https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/257) that suggests using `export -f` to export the functions. I tried that:

```
# This function should be available as a command.
function gcd () {
}

# Bash completions for gcd
_gcd_completions () {
}

export -f gcd
complete -F _gcd_completions gcd
```

But it didn't change the behavior.

I also tried just `export`, as well as `declare -fx`, to no avail.

I noticed that if I directly `source /etc/profile` from an X terminal, then the command (and the completions, fwiw) starts to work. So I know the syntax and everything is at least correct, and I know that */etc/profile* is executing the script and setting up the command. It's just not automatically working in any of these interactive shell consoles.

I also notice that some env vars that I have declared in other */etc/profile.d* scripts are available in interactive shells, so I know */etc/profile* is doing something in these shells.

How can I make this work?

Comment: IIRC the .bash_profile (eventually) sources the /etc/profile.d scripts (follow what gets source'd), but an interactive bash shell does not source .bash_profile. You could add to .bashrc: `[[ -f $HOME/.bash_profile ]] && . "$HOME"/.bash_profile` -- make sure your .bash_profile does not source .bashrc

Comment: Exporting of functions from `/etc/profile.d/*` works on ArchLinux without sourcing these scripts in every interactive shell. It doesn't work on Ubuntu.